# Nested/multiple brace-matching in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

In Notepad++, is it possible to force all (or at least the 3 or 4 deepest) pairs of braces/brackets/parens/etc. that enclose the cursor to become highlighted? Preferably in different colors for each matched pair?

For instance, in this example:

```
int main(char** args)
{
  if(blah)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

If we place the cursor anywhere in the if-block, the main function's opening and closing braces should become one color, while the if-block's braces become another. The coloring for each block should stay the same as long the cursor is still in that block.